# Pass Env parameter to Angular 1 application by Jenkins Job

Tags: angularjs, jenkins

We are developing Angular 1 application. 
So in time of project assembling in Jenkins job i parse index.html and set global parameter depending on env: prod or dev.
This is part of index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.PROJECT_CONST = {
    env: '%CLOUDFRONT_ENV%'
  };
</script>
```

And this is how i parse it via Jenkins

```
sed -i "s/%CLOUDFRONT_ENV%/prod/g" generated/index.html
```

After that i'm using this env parameter in components where it is needed ( for example for generating link to online help )

I know that polluting global namespace is kind of bad practice.
Is there better solution for specifying environment via Jenkins.

Thank you in advance.